# How to read only one element of the input? or one char

Tags: c

I have a problem when a user input `a2, aa1, sjshah1hasua` or anything on the line has 1 or 2 it will still read and proceed to execute the program. I want to prompt this as error when user input something like that. I'm still new to programming.
My function:

```
void exit()
{
    int out;
    system("cls");
    printf("\n are you sure you want to exit?");
    printf("\n [1] Yes");
    printf("\n [2] No");
    scanf("%d", &out);
    if (out==1) {
        printf("\n exit..");
        getch();
    }
    else if (out==2) {
        printf("\n back to menu..);
        getch();
        system("cls");
        menu();
    }
    else {
        getchar() != '\n'; // to prevent errors when user input a char or string//
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are new to programming... have you been learning C?  Or C++?  There is a difference.

Comment: This looks like C code (not C++) and is not an [MCVE]. BTW, `getch` is not a standard function. At last, better end your `printf` format control strings with `\n` (or call [fflush](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) appropriately) since `stdout` is usually line-buffered. And please read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Post a [MCVE] as required here please.

Comment: "getchar() != '\n';" and "getchar();" do the same thing

Comment: Notice that [exit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit) is a standard function, so avoid (at least for readability) calling your function with that name